# Why does Boost::multiprecision::sqrt(1) return 0?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-multiprecision

Boost::multiprecision::sqrt(1) seems to return 0

```
#include <boost/multiprecision/cpp_int.hpp>
#include <boost/multiprecision/number.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
   namespace mp = boost::multiprecision;
   mp::cpp_int i(1); 
   cout << "i == " << i << endl;
   cout << "mp::sqrt(i) == " << mp::sqrt(i) << endl;
}
```

Output:
i == 1
mp::sqrt(i) == 0

I expect that sqrt(1) == 1.

I get the same results on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6976cd205e5543e) and on my local installation with gcc and Boost 1.62.  Does this happen to others?  Am I missing something or is this a bug?

Comment: Eeerm, what else do you expect?

Comment: I expect sqrt(1) == 1

Comment: This looks 100% like a bug and very poor tests for edge cases.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/068a750da56b55d1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is definitely a bug. It was reported to the Boost bug tracker 3 days ago as [ticket #12559](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/12559).

Comment: Thanks! Don't know how I missed this in the bug tracker.